# OnClickListener on Views inside a custom ScrollView

Tags: android

I'm havin a horizontal ScrollView inside a ViewPager. To prevent the ViewPager to be scrolled when the end of the ScrollView is reached I use this class as per hint on SO:

```
public class CustomScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView {

public CustomScrollView(Context p_context, AttributeSet p_attrs) {
    super(p_context, p_attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent p_event) {

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent p_event) {


    if (p_event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
            && getParent() != null) {
        getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(p_event);
}
}
```

The `onInterCeptTouchEvent` seems to consume any click to that View and everything inside it. When I put `Views` into that `ScrollView`, their `OnClickListener`s won't be called.

When I let `onInterceptTouchEvent` return false, the `OnClickListener`s are called, but the `ScrollView` can't be scrolled.

How can I put clickable Views inside that `ScrollView`?

EDIT: After implementing Rotem's answer, the `onClickListener` works, but it doesn't only fire on click events but also on others, like fling. How can this be prevented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, minutes after starting a bounty I found out how it works:

in `onInterceptTouchEvent` I

```
return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(p_event);
```

Comment: if you only call super with same arguments, there's no need to override the method

Comment: Ensure you read the [Javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) for your methods, which describes your problem. As Rotem says, you don't need to implement this one.

Answer (score 11):

try to call `onTouchEvent` inside the implementation of `onInterceptTouchEvent` and then return false.

Answer (score 1):

Here is complete solution using answers to this question.

```
public class CustomHorizontalScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView {

        public CustomHorizontalScrollView(Context context) {
                super(context);

        }
        public CustomHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                super(context, attrs);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
                boolean result = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
                if(onTouchEvent(ev)) {
                        return result;
                } else {
                        return false;
                }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
                    && getParent() != null) {
                getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            }
                return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        }

}
```